# Trigger to copy related list

Tags: trigger

I am completely stuck on how to get started with this. 
My application works like this:
I create an Opportunity, when the status is set to closed won, a contract is created and a renewal policy is created. When the renewal policy is set to closed won, a new contract is created (along with another renewal policy). So this is quite a simple process.

The problem that is not so simple is, Contract has a Junction object to address:

```
Contract -------- ContractAddressJunction -------------- Address
```

When the new contract is created from the renewal opportunity, I want to attach the same addresses to the new Contract.

I really don't know how to get started, I am already failing at the query.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Opp1 gets set to closed won

Contract1 and Opp2 (renewal policy) get created <-- Opp2 should have a lookup to Contract1

Opp2 gets set to closed won <-- your Opp trigger should check if the Opps in trigger.new just got set to Closed Won; You should then scope out all Contracts based on the lookup I mentioned

Then you can select all the junction objects for those contracts

Now create your Contract2s and insert

Now you need to loop round the scoped junction objects and clone each one but change the Contract lookup (or master-detail) to the correct Contract2 (if you're having trouble with this bit I will put some sample code together, but give it a go first :) )

**Update - sample code**

Hopefully this will get you started! It's untested but should show the general concept. Notice the new Contract also relate to the Opp that caused them to be created.

```
Set<Id> conIds = new Set<Id>();
List<Contract> consToIns = new List<Contract>();
List<Opportunity> scopedOpps = new List<Opportunity>();

for (Opportunity opp : trigger.new) {
    if (null != opp.Contract__c) {
        conIds.add(opp.Contract__c);

        Contract con = new Contract();
        con.Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
        consToIns.add(con);
        scopedOpps.add(opp);
    }
}

Map<Id, Contract> consWithJunc = new Map<Id, Contract>([SELECT Id,
                                      (SELECT Id,
                                              Contract__c,
                                              Address__c
                                       FROM Con_Add_Juncs__r)
                               FROM Contract
                               WHERE Id IN :conIds]);

insert consToIns;

Map<Id, Contract> newConsByOppId = new Map<Id, Contract>();
for (Contract con : consToIns) {
    newConsByOppId.put(con.Opporunity__c, con);
}

List<Con_Add_Juncs__r> newConAdds = new List<Con_Add_Juncs__r>();

for (Opportunity opp : scopedOpps) {
    Contract con = consWithJunc.get(opp.Contract__c);

    for (Con_Add_Juncs__r conAdd : con.Con_Add_Juncs__r) {
        Con_Add_Juncs__c newConAdd = conAdd.clone();
        newConAdd.Contract__c = newConsByOppId.get(opp.Id).Id;
        newConAdds.add(newConAdd);
    }
}

insert newConAdds;
```

Comment: I have already implemented the first bit. It works fine. The thing I am having problems with is writing the query to get the addresses for contract 1 and then attaching it to contract 2.

Comment: Ah ok, you did say you were stuck getting started ;) When I get a chance I'll write you some sample code

Comment: Do you think you could get me started on the query?

Comment: Hello, I have just tried this and it says that it doesn't know the relationship `Con_Add_Juncs__r`. I obviously renamed it to the correct junction object, so not sure what's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use the Salesforce workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) or the schema in eclipse to find out the relationship name on the Contract object for the junction object

Comment: Hi - I still haven't sorted this out yet. I looked up the relationship name using schema explorer in the IDE, but it still tells me that it doesn't understand the relationship.